# Записать пары уникальных значений из 2 таблиц

Tags: sql, sql-server

Привет.
Имеется 3 таблицы `*Пользователь* (с полем idUser)`, `*Событие*(с полем idMeeting)`, `*СобытиеПользователя*(с полями idUser, idMeeting)`.

## Вопрос:

Необходимо вставить в таблицу `*СобытиеПользователя*` комбинацию из `idUser`, `idMeeting`. Но комбинация должна быть следующая: все значения `idUser` из таблицы *Пользователь* ставятся в соответствие значению `idMeeting` (которое мы задаем сами), причем если такая комбинация имеется мы ее пропускаем.

## Например:

В таблице `*Пользователь*` имеются:

```
idUser 
  1
  2
  3
```

в таблице `*Событие*`

```
idMeeting
    1
    5
    6
```

в таблице `*СобытиеПользователя*` 1 запись:

```
idUser idMeeting 
  1        1
```

Теперь мы хотим записать в таблицу
`*СобытиеПользователя*` с `idMeeting = 1` всех Пользоваетелей, т.е. таблица `*СобытиеПользователя*` после записи будет выглядеть следующим образом:

```
idMeeting    idUser   
  1            1 (эта запись была)  
  1            5 (это добавили)    
  1            6 (это добавили)
```

Причем если мы хотим вставить повторяющуюся пару, мы ее не вставляем.

Comment: Несколько раз прочитал вопрос, но так ничего и не понял

Comment: @BuilderC попытался поправить. Так понятнее?

Comment: у вас в примере результатов явно перепутаны колонки

Comment: @PashaPash спасибо. Поправил.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Примерно так:

```sql
DECLARE @idMeeting INT = 1

INSERT INTO [СобытиеПользователя]
(idUser, idMeeting)
SELECT idUser, @idMeeting
FROM [Пользователь]
WHERE idUser NOT IN (
    SELECT idUser FROM [СобытиеПользователя] 
    WHERE idMeeting = @idMeeting 
)
```